# Keep rows with true overlaps time period in pandas using specific columns values

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am working with a data frame shown below. Within there are 2 columns that I would like to find out true time overlap rows based on **values_1** column. The **values_1** column has multiple item that repeats and from that I would only like to extract rows where the start date_time and end date_time (both datetime) overlap for that specific value within values_1 column.

Below is data frame I have:

| values_1 | uniqId | DeptId | Start DateTime | End DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VGM | 1278 | BKNG | 2023-09-05 18:35:28 | 2023-09-05 20:05:28 |
| VGM | 1259 | BKNG | 2023-09-05 18:55:18 | 2023-09-05 19:25:38 |
| VGM | 2567 | BKNG | 2023-09-05 14:29:38 | 2023-09-05 17:35:28 |
| WEH | 9854 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 13:45:58 | 2023-09-05 15:00:00 |
| WEH | 9124 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 17:25:28 | 2023-09-05 19:43:13 |
| WEH | 9785 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 16:15:21 | 2023-09-05 18:24:02 |
| POH | 3479 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 15:35:29 | 2023-09-05 17:25:22 |
| POH | 3449 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 17:35:28 | 2023-09-05 18:35:19 |

And the output table I would like to achieve is:

| values_1 | uniqId | DeptId | Start DateTime | End DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VGM | 1278 | BKNG | 2023-09-05 18:35:28 | 2023-09-05 20:05:28 |
| VGM | 1259 | BKNG | 2023-09-05 18:55:18 | 2023-09-05 19:25:38 |
| WEH | 9124 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 17:25:28 | 2023-09-05 19:43:13 |
| WEH | 9785 | ASKG | 2023-09-05 16:15:21 | 2023-09-05 18:24:02 |

So from above output table, POH is completely removed because no time overlaps. Along with VGM and WEH 2 rows are dropped because their times did not overlap with among **values_1** items.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

I looked at different overlapping time periods example with no luck that I can apply to my data frame.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the times, then use a [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.shift.html) to compare the successive rows for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# ensure datetime
df[['Start DateTime', 'End DateTime']] = df[['Start DateTime', 'End DateTime']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# sort values
tmp = df.sort_values(by=['values_1', 'Start DateTime', 'End DateTime'])

# are consecutive intervals overlapping?
m = tmp['Start DateTime'].lt(tmp.groupby('values_1')['End DateTime'].shift())

# flag rows and previous ones
out = df.loc[m|m.groupby(tmp['values_1']).shift(-1)]
```

Output:

```
  values_1  uniqId DeptId      Start DateTime        End DateTime
0      VGM    1278   BKNG 2023-09-05 18:35:28 2023-09-05 20:05:28
1      VGM    1259   BKNG 2023-09-05 18:55:18 2023-09-05 19:25:38
4      WEH    9124   ASKG 2023-09-05 17:25:28 2023-09-05 19:43:13
5      WEH    9785   ASKG 2023-09-05 16:15:21 2023-09-05 18:24:02
```

Intermediates:

```
  values_1  uniqId DeptId      Start DateTime        End DateTime           end_shift      m m_shift  m|m_shift
6      POH    3479   ASKG 2023-09-05 15:35:29 2023-09-05 17:25:22                 NaT  False   False      False
7      POH    3449   ASKG 2023-09-05 17:35:28 2023-09-05 18:35:19 2023-09-05 17:25:22  False     NaN      False
2      VGM    2567   BKNG 2023-09-05 14:29:38 2023-09-05 17:35:28                 NaT  False   False      False
0      VGM    1278   BKNG 2023-09-05 18:35:28 2023-09-05 20:05:28 2023-09-05 17:35:28  False    True       True
1      VGM    1259   BKNG 2023-09-05 18:55:18 2023-09-05 19:25:38 2023-09-05 20:05:28   True     NaN       True
3      WEH    9854   ASKG 2023-09-05 13:45:58 2023-09-05 15:00:00                 NaT  False   False      False
5      WEH    9785   ASKG 2023-09-05 16:15:21 2023-09-05 18:24:02 2023-09-05 15:00:00  False    True       True
4      WEH    9124   ASKG 2023-09-05 17:25:28 2023-09-05 19:43:13 2023-09-05 18:24:02   True     NaN       True
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for providing answer to this question. If you can please help me why am I getting this error? ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
I appreciate it. Thank you! How to go about this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Which line of code is raising the error? Can you try to reset the index of your input? `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: Reset_index() worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help in this. I have additional question, what if the data is not consecutive intervals overlapping? What do I need to do then? The current data is still showing me the overlaps with some values_1. Appreciate your help with it. Thanks!

Comment: I have additional question, what if the data is not consecutive intervals overlapping? What do I need to do then? The current data is still showing me the overlaps with some values_1. Appreciate your help with it. Thanks!